# Finding the extremal of the functional (simple pendulum)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Given a system composed by a simple pendulum that is abandoned from rest at $t=0$,
$\theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Find the extremal of the functional for this system:

> $J(\theta)=\int(\frac{m}{2}l^2\theta'^2+mgl\cos(\theta))dt$

**My approach to the solution**

I started by applying the Euler-Lagrange equation, and got the following result:

> $-mgl\sin(\theta)-ml^2\theta''=0$

If I got the correct result and understood the problem , now I need to solve this ODE in order to have the Extremal of the given function, is that right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Use, for example, `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$.